# React (Native) and Component Life Cycle and Event Handling

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router

I have been learning React Native with Expo. Decided to work on a small two screens app to understand the 'React way' but I couldn't figure out how to think in React.

I believe I don't understand component life cycles enough. In the example code below my console output is:

- home render
- header render
- *home render* (why home is rendering again?)
- header will receive props
- header render

Since my header is a custom component for StackNavigator I can't pass an event handler to it via props (afaik?) so I have to make a *setParams* calls in HomeScreen's componentDidMount / WillMount events but when I do that my entire HomeScreen re-renders itself just why?

What will happen when I have a FlatListView in my HomeScreen that could potentially display 100s of items. My home screen and all of it's children will re-render itself right at the start?

Passing props to custom navigation header is also another thing I don't fully understand. I have no idea how to pass screen specific navigationOptions to my custom header. Say if I decided to pass a "title" parameter per screen if I define speciic *navigationOptions* properties on Routes my custom header does not get those parameters.

Here is my code:

**Router.js**

```
export const RootStack = StackNavigator(
{
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
},
{
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) =>
    {
        return { header: <MainHeader navigation={navigation} /> }
    }
});
```

**App.js**

```
class App() {
    render() {
        return <RootStack />
    }
}
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.refCheck = "Home Screen";
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ onMenuClick: this._handleMenuClick });
    }

    _handleMenuClick = () => {
        console.log("Handle menu click. - " + this.refCheck);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("home render");
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

**MainHeader.js**

```
export default class MainHeader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("header will receive props");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("header render");
        return (
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
                <Text>Logo</Text>
                <Text>Search</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I've switched my navigation component to wix react-native-navigation one. It helped me understand most of the things thanks to the AMAZING documentation compared to react navigation. Component life cycle topic is still open and I will update my own answer when I get a better understanding.